# How is the stainless-steel tubing in rocket engines brought into the correct shape?

Tags: engines, manufacturing, combustion-chamber

Some American rocket engines have TCA's (thrust chamber assemblies) built after a certain scheme:

A combustion chamber, including part of the nozzle, made of several dozens of stainless steel tubes running alongside the exhaust gas, brazed together (also referred to as longitudinal tubewall chamber) plus sometimes an nozzle extension.

However, one thing that left me baffled is: How were these tubes brought into a proper shape to be made into a nozzle? As the cross-section of the combustion chamber varies, so has the tubing, and as seen in Hazel and Huang below, the cross-section may not even remain circular.

Hazel and Huang make a comment about the manufacturing of these tubes here in their book, but unfortunately, details are left out.

[image]

[image]

NASA SP-8087 also describes the process, but again, no details.

What I'd like to know is: Do we have video footage / images or a more detailed description of this manufacturing process and/or the tooling that was used in it? One source which I'm unfortunately not able to recall claimed that this process was very difficult and prone to failure, thus for each engine they wanted to build an order was placed for three times the tubes necessary, all of them had their performance estimated by undergoing flow-tests and two thirds with the worst performance were simply discarded.

Edit: This is a question specifically regarding the manufacturing process of stainless steel tubing with varying cross-section.

Comment: I don't think it's correct that the tubes get mashed into square-ish shapes. I think it's more that they get brazed together at the points where the circles touch. I'm out of town right now but when I get back, I have some pictures I took of the actual tubes in the SSME, and unless I'm misremembering, they are round.  BTW, I am not the down voter and I'm baffled as to why this got downvoted.

Comment: Check out this picture of the inside of an F-1. You can see the tubes are still round. https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/eande-plate-huge-exhibit.jpg

Comment: "All american rocket engines I know of": I think only the RL-10 and RS-25E are still built that way, and Rocketdyne's experimenting with a 3D printed thrust chamber for the RL-10, while the RS-25E only uses it because development of a more modern channel wall version got cut. Modern practice is to use milled or 3D printed channel walls.

Comment: Related question with informative comments and answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30588/6944

Comment: Here http://heroicrelics.org/cosmosphere/engines-h-1-cut-away/dsc45328.jpg.html is an example of circular and square-ish shape within the same engine.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  I should have stated that I don't really know about how modern engines are made, I always was more interrested in the 'retro' side of things, primarily anything that took place in the 60s. Also, whoever downvoted probably believed that I didn't read up on the related question you sent me, but I have already read it and it did not really satisfy me, which is why I wanted to ask this in the first place. This question is specifically regarding the manufacturing process.

Comment: I did realize that I was very wrong about all american engines following this design practice though, even back then there were many different practices used.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm very focused on 60's rocket engines and are not up to date with modern practices, I should have mentioned that. I did realize that I was very wrong about all american engines following this design practice though, even back then there were many different practices used.

Comment: I'm a retired mech engr, spent a career in design work and getting my designs actually into production and aircraft qualified. After reading (mostly viewing) your references it seems to me they are quite clear in how this was accomplished. Imagine a very and long slender balloon that is half inflated. This limp balloon is placed into the grooves of a machined toolset which has complex shapes like a molding toolset. Then the long/slender balloon is pressurized to 'fill out' to match the profile of the toolset. The balloon then freezes in this new shape. Viola... somewhat extreme sections.

Comment: Of course, just an educated guess. Your mileage may vary. No substitutions, no returns.

Comment: look into hydroforming of tubing

Comment: If hydroforming can produce aluminum bicycle frames capable of withstanding 15m jumps - then it can probably be applied to steel tubing.

Comment: @BradV Very good tip! That was the kind of answer I wanted to hear!

Comment: on further consideration there are portions of the 
 final tubing cross section profile that are not 100% compatible with inserting a raw round tube into a toolset. Perhaps some preforming (squishing round tube to almost flat) was done. Preheating of tubing to enhance ductility goes without saying. Frequently I've said to other engineers "when someone says 'it goes without saying'... it MUST be said to some people."

Comment: @BradV Yes, this seems quite likely. I am not experienced with metalworking, but foolproofing a prodution process must be extremely difficult.